# How do I force jarsign to sign jarfiles?

Tags: java, jar, jarsigner

Our product is halted at Java version 1.5.0_13 and we would like to upgrade.  Our software deploys a large number of jars via Java Web Start; all of these jars must be signed.  However, a couple of the jars do not contain class files, and starting with Java version 1.5.0_14, it appears that the jarsign utility chooses not to sign any jar that does not contain class files.

What can I do to force jarsign to sign these jars?  Or what can I do to distribute these jars through Java Web Start without signing them?  And is there anywhere where this change to jarsign with versions 1.5.0_14 and above is documented?  I can't find it in the [release notes](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/ReleaseNotes.html).

Comment: can you show the commands you use to create the signed jar files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not able to verify that there is any problem. Can you look through and see what might be different in your environment? I'm running on Windows 7 RC.

Let's check the version:

```
C:\temp>java -version
java version "1.5.0_14"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_14-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_14-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Let's see what'll be in our jar:

```
C:\temp>dir /s /b com
C:\temp\com\rdc
C:\temp\com\rdc\test
C:\temp\com\rdc\test\logging.properties
```

Let's make the jar:

```
C:\temp>jar -cfv test-source.jar com/*
added manifest
adding: com/rdc/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: com/rdc/test/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: com/rdc/test/logging.properties(in = 13) (out= 15)(deflated -15%)
```

Let's sign the jar: I'm using a self-signed certificate.

```
C:\temp>jarsigner -signedjar test-dest.jar test-source.jar vinay
Enter Passphrase for keystore:

Warning: The signer certificate will expire within six months.
```

Let's see what's in our signed jar:

```
C:\temp>jar tvf test-dest.jar
   155 Wed Jul 15 23:39:12 BST 2009 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   276 Wed Jul 15 23:39:12 BST 2009 META-INF/VINAY.SF
  1130 Wed Jul 15 23:39:12 BST 2009 META-INF/VINAY.DSA
     0 Wed Jul 15 23:37:18 BST 2009 META-INF/
     0 Wed Jul 15 19:44:44 BST 2009 com/rdc/
     0 Wed Jul 15 19:44:58 BST 2009 com/rdc/test/
    13 Wed Jul 15 23:37:10 BST 2009 com/rdc/test/logging.properties
```

OK, it certainly appears to have been signed, and it has no classes. Let's look at the contents of `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.5.0_14 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Name: com/rdc/test/logging.properties
SHA1-Digest: Ob/S+a7TLh+akYGEFIDugM12S88=
```

And the contents of `VINAY.SF`:

```
Signature-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.5.0_14 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
SHA1-Digest-Manifest-Main-Attributes: 4bEkze9MHmgfBoY+fnoS1V9bRPs=
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: YB8QKIAQPjEYh8PkuGA5G8pW3tw=

Name: com/rdc/test/logging.properties
SHA1-Digest: qXCyrUvUALII7SBNEq4R7G8lVQQ=
```

Now, let's verify the jar:

```
C:\temp>jarsigner -verify -verbose test-dest.jar

         155 Wed Jul 15 23:51:34 BST 2009 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
         276 Wed Jul 15 23:51:34 BST 2009 META-INF/VINAY.SF
        1131 Wed Jul 15 23:51:34 BST 2009 META-INF/VINAY.DSA
           0 Wed Jul 15 23:37:18 BST 2009 META-INF/
           0 Wed Jul 15 19:44:44 BST 2009 com/rdc/
           0 Wed Jul 15 19:44:58 BST 2009 com/rdc/test/
smk       13 Wed Jul 15 23:37:10 BST 2009 com/rdc/test/logging.properties

  s = signature was verified
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
  i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope

jar verified.

Warning: This jar contains entries whose signer certificate will expire within
six months. Re-run with the -verbose and -certs options for more details.
```

On the face of it, everything appears to be in order. Can you check if your certificates have expired, or been revoked? Are you using self-signed certs or real certs? Or have I misunderstood what your problem is?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone searching on this issue, we determined it only affects certain later versions of Java 1.5, those from 1.5.0_14 onward, I believe.  It appears to be fixed in the latest versions of 1.5, and is definitely fixed in 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

You can put dummy class files in if you need to. Probably distasteful but maybe necessary.

Comment: Yes, we found a purpose for the Hello World java app :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a long shot, but the Ant [SignJar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/signjar.html) might be able to convince jarsign to do the right thing. There's a bunch of options there that might tip the balance.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, I tried the same thing as Vinay, but with the JDK 1.5.0_17 jarsigner, and a proper Verisign certificate, and got the same results.  Jarsigner worked, and the jar verified using jarsigner -verify.

Answer (score 1):

Adding about it : I'm using Java Web Start, and I have a jar which contains only images.
With a JDK 1.6_05(07, 10, too), and an Ant generation, it is signed without a problem (with a self-signed cert).
So, like others described, it doesn't seem to be linked to the jar containing .class files or not.